# Properties of iid Cauchy random variables

Tags: probability-theory, solution-verification

Suppose $X_i$, $i \in \mathbb{N}$ are iid Cauchy random variables.  I want to solve the following questions, part of which I have done:

(1) Find necessary and sufficient conditions for the sequence $\phi_j$ such that $\sum_{j =1}^n \phi_j X_j$ converges almost surely.

(2) Show that there exist constants $K_1, K_2 >0$ such that $$\frac{K_1}{x+1} \leq P(|X_1| > x) \leq \frac{K_2}{x+1} $$ for every $x \ge 0$.

(3) Find necessary and sufficient conditions on $\phi_j$ so that $\sum_{j=1}^\infty |\phi_j X_j|$converges almost surely.

---

**My attempt:**

For (1), we have convergence almost surely if and only if we have convergence in distribution (since we are dealing with an independent sum, by Levy's theorem for random series).  Convergence in distribution holds if and only if $$E\left( \exp\left( \sum_{j=1}^n t \phi_j X_j\right) \right) = \exp \left( -|t| \sum_{j=1}^n |\phi_j|\right)$$ converges to a function $f(t)$ which is continuous at $t = 0$ by Levy's continuity theorem, which is true if and only if $\sum_{j=1}^\infty |\phi_j|$ converges.  I'm not 100% sure this is correct.  Am I wrong here?

For (2), I have started but cannot finish.  Note that for $u \ge 0, x\ge 0$, $(u+1)^2 \ge u^2+1$ so that $$P(|X_1|>x) = \frac{2}{\pi} \int_x^\infty \frac{1}{1+u^2} du \ge \frac{2}{\pi} \int_x^\infty \frac{1}{(1+u)^2} du = \frac{2/\pi}{1+x}$$ so taking $K_1 = 2/\pi$ suffices.

I am unsure how to do the upper bound or part (3), but perhaps (3) has to do with the fact that $\{\limsup \sum_{j=1}^n |X_j \phi_j| = \infty\}$ is tail measurable so we only need to show that it has probability < 1.  Any help would be massively appreciated!

Comment: You also have $$\int_x^\infty\frac{du}{1+u^2}<\int_x^\infty\frac{du}{u^2}.$$

Comment: I know that - in fact I thought it might work at first , but that gives $$\int_x^\infty \frac{1}{u^2} du = \frac{1}{x}$$ and there are NO CONSTANTS $K$ such that $$\frac{K}{1+x} \ge \frac{1}{x}$$ for every $x \ge 0$

Comment: You just need a constant $K$ so that $$\frac K{1+x} \ge \min\left\{\frac1x, 1\right\} .$$

Comment: Ok so take $K_2 = 2$ for example works, since then $K_2/(1+x) \ge 1$ on $x \in [0,1]$ so it trivially bounds the probability there and for $x > 1, x/(1+x) > 1/2 > 1/\pi$, so we may rearrange to conclude.  Thank you both for this.

Comment: I think your issue is that you have a hard time making approximations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Part 3, let's use Kolmogorov's Three Series Theorem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%27s_three-series_theorem

We know that nothing will work if the $\phi_j$ are unbounded.  So let's assume they are bounded.

For any $A>0$, we ask

1. Does $\sum_j P(|\phi_j X_j|) > A)$ converge?
2. Does $\sum_j E(|\phi_j X_j| I_{|\phi_j X_j| \le A})$ converge?
3. Does $\sum_j \text{Var}(|\phi_j X_j| I_{|\phi_j X_j| \le A})$ converge?

For example, for (2) we have the formula
$$ E(|\phi_j X_j| I_{|\phi_j X_j| \le A}) = \int_0^{A/|\phi_j|} \frac{|\phi_j|2r\, dr}{1+r^2} \approx \min\{A^2/|\phi_j|, |\phi_j| \log(A/|\phi_j|)\} $$
So we can see that (2) holds if and only if
$$ |\phi_j| \to 0 \quad\text{and}\quad \sum_{j:|\phi_j| < 1/2} |\phi_j| \log(|\phi_j|) \quad\text{converges.}\tag{*} $$
If you look at (1) and (3), you find that they hold if and only if $\sum_j|\phi_j|$ converges.  So the answer to Part 3 is if and only if $(*)$ holds.

Comment: The last part is wrong. How do you get absolute convergence from convergence?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy What was I thinking?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I did a complete redo.

Comment: This is helpful - I should really know to use the three series theorem in this case.  I'm very confused about how you finalize these conditions:  For the sum of the probabilities converging, since by my part (2), we have bounds proportional to $1/(1+x)$, we have $$\sum_{j=1}^\infty P(|\phi_j X_j| > A) < \infty \iff \sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{|\phi_j|}{|\phi_j| + A} < \infty$$  For the sum of the expectations, I get $$E(|X_j \phi_j| \mathbf{1}(|X_j \phi_j| \leq A)) = \frac{|\phi_j|}{\pi} \log \left(1 + \frac{A^2}{\phi_j^2}\right)$$ Is this correct?  I don't see how it matches with your conclusion.

Comment: Also I get something ludicrously complicated for the variance, namely $$\frac{2}{\pi} A |\phi_j| - \frac{2 |\phi_j|^2}{\pi} \arctan \left( \frac{A}{|\phi_j|} \right) - \frac{|\phi_j|^2}{\pi^2} \log^2 \left(1 + \frac{A^2}{\phi_j^2} \right) $$  I have no idea how you can say this converges for every $A$ if and only if $\sum |\phi_j|$ converges

Comment: Yes, your answer for the expectation and mine are the same.  Remember I only provided an approximation.

Comment: And a good approcimation for your variance formula (at least when $|\phi_j|$ is small) is $A/|\phi_j|$.

Comment: And also, $\frac{|\phi_j|}{|\phi_j|+A} \approx |\phi_j|$ if $|\phi_j|$ is small.

Comment: I understand these things intuitively, but I was having trouble showing rigorously that $\sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{|\phi_j|}{A+|\phi_j|}$ converges iff $\sum |\phi_j|$ converges nonetheless. The $\impliedby$ direction is trivial.  For the $\implies$ direction we have $\sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{|\phi_j|}{A+|\phi_j|}$ converges $\implies \frac{|\phi_j|}{A+|\phi_j|} \rightarrow 0 \implies |\phi_j| \rightarrow 0$.  So if we choose $c$ such that $1/c - A > 0$, then for $|\phi_j| < 1/c - A$, we have $c|\phi_j| < \frac{|\phi_j|}{A+|\phi_j|}$, and this inequality holds for each $j \ge J$ (for some $J$)

Comment: If $|\phi_j|$ is sufficiently small, say $\\phi_j| < \epsilon$, then there exist constants $K_1>0$ and $K_2>0$ (depending upon $A$)  such that $K_1 \frac{|\phi_j|}{A+\phi_j}\le |\phi_j| \le K_2 \frac{|\phi_j|}{A+\phi_j}$.

Comment: Now if $\phi_j| \to 0$, then the convergence of $\sum_j |\phi_j|$ is equivalent to the convergence of $\sum_{j:|\phi_j| \le \epsilon} |\phi_j|$, because their difference is only finitely many terms.

Comment: You can do this kind of argument again and again.  This way the intuition becomes rigorous.

Comment: Also, to see that there exists $K_1, K_2 > 0$ such that $K_1 f(x) \le g(x) \le K_2 f(x)$ for $x$ sufficiently small, you only need to establish that $f(x)/g(x)$ converges to a non-zero limit as $x \to 0$.

Comment: Ok so the first condition of the three series theorem makes sense to me.  The other two approximations (the expectation and variance conditions) are very confusing.  I know $\log (1+x) = x - c^2/2$ for some $c \in (1, 1+x$ assuming $x > 0$ which it would be in this case so that $$|\phi_j|\log \left( 1+ \frac{A^2}{\phi_j^2} \right) \leq \frac{A^2}{|\phi_j|}$$ but this approximation gets worse as $\phi_j \rightarrow 0$.  How do you get the second approximation in your answer, and what about the one for the variance?

Comment: I had a $\min$.  When $\phi_j$ is small, it is the second term that is smaller.

Comment: I know it's smaller for small $|\phi_j|$, but I'm not sure how you get the second approximation (by $|\phi_j| \log (A/|\phi|_j)$) to start off with.  Do you still use a Taylor series approach?  Sorry to have so many questions about this - I really am not experienced with approximations of logarithms in particular

Comment: The expected value can be computed by $2 |\phi_j| \int_0^{A/|\phi_j} \frac {r \, dr}{1+r^2}$.  This I approximated with $\min\{|\phi_j| \int_0^{A/|\phi_j} r \, dr + |\phi_j| \int_1^{A/|\phi_j} \frac {dr}{r}\}$.

Comment: Actually wait we know that (using your hint from earlier) since $$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\log(1+A^2/x^2)}{\log(1+A/|x|)} = 2 $$ so we have convergence of the expectations if and only if we have convergence of $\sum |\phi_j|\log(A/|\phi|_j)$ which is convergence if and only if $\sum |\phi_j|\log(|\phi_j|)$ since we know from the first condition that $\sum |\phi_j|$ converges.  That handles the second condition in the three series theorem.

Comment: That works too.  The nice thing about approximations is that you can do things in many different ways.

Comment: Now for the third, we need to verify that $\sum |\phi_j|^2 \arctan(A/|\phi_j|)$ and $\sum |\phi_j|^2 \log^2( 1 + A^2 /\phi_j^2)$ both converge

Comment: The first series dominates the second.  So you only need to consider the first.

Comment: Which first series?  You mean that $\sum |\phi_j|$ dominates both of the above series for small $\phi_j$?  That works I think.  Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Well, the first series is equivalent to $\sum |\phi_j|$.  But yes, that is what I meant.

Comment: Are you ready to accept my answer?

Comment: Could you upvote my answer as well?  Then I am on my way to getting a silver tag for answering real analysis questions.